# How do I combine output of foreach into one variable?

Tags: php

I have to pass the content of a post into a method for it to post into Wordpress correctly. All the content posted will go into a $content variable thats passed to the method. How can I get the contents of a foreach loop into the $content variable?

```
<?php
$return = '';
foreach ($response['daily']['data'] as $cond) {

echo '<br /><br /><strong>' . date('l, F j, Y', $cond['time']) .'</strong><br />

<div id="dailysummary"><br />Daily Summary: ' . $cond['summary'] . '<br /><br /></div>

<table style="border:1px solid #ccc">

<tr>
<td>
High
</td>
<td>
'.round($cond['temperatureMax']).'
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
Low
</td>
<td>
'.round($cond['temperatureMin']).'
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
Chance of precip.
</td>
<td>
'.round($cond['precipProbability']).'%
</td>
</tr>   


<tr>
<td>
Wind speed
</td>
<td>
'.round($cond['windSpeed']).' mph
</td>
</tr>   



<tr>
<td>
Dewpoint.
</td>
<td>
'.round($cond['dewPoint']).'
</td>
</tr>   


<tr>
<td>
Humidity
</td>
<td>
'.round($cond['humidity']).'
</td>
</tr>   

</table>



<br /><br />';

}
```

Comment: @nogad OP can also have earned the reputation in other topics and programming languages.

Comment: @nogad Yeah I don't understand that too. He seems to be new to PHP and most of his points come from ASP.NET and C#, but concatenating is the same thing in every language I know

Comment: sure its different per language, but you should know the words to google? @Rizier123

Comment: @nogad Yes that is true even without having any reputation :) But just reputation on its own doesn't say in which topics OP is good in.

Comment: i hope rep says "i know how computers work AND i can use google" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Either build vars instead of echoing:

```
$html = '';
foreach(...) {
   $html .= '... build html here...';
}
```

Or keep your current code, and use output buffering:

```
ob_start();
foreach(...) {
   echo '... html goes here ...';
}
$html = ob_get_clean();
```

There's no right/wrong way of doing this. Either way you're going to end up with a chunk of html in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$content = "";

foreach ($response['daily']['data'] as $cond) {

$content .= '<br /><br /><strong>' . date('l, F j, Y', $cond['time']) .'</strong><br />
[...]
```

You'll create an empty string and add more text to it on every loop.

Answer (score 0):

Like so--using `.=` operator:

```
$content = '';

foreach ($response['daily']['data'] as $cond) {

   $content .= '<br /><br /><strong>' . date('l, F j, Y', $cond['time']).'</strong><br />

   <div id="dailysummary"><br />Daily Summary: ' . $cond['summary'] . '<br /><br /></div>

    <table style="border:1px solid #ccc">
    ... ';

}

print $content;
```